# How to verify a page title using WebDriver and page object?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, pageobjects

I am trying to write a method to verify page title using page objects but I am unable to do it. Could you please help me out how to write a method to verify page title after searching something in the google page.

Here is my 2 classes.

### Class 1

```
public class GoogleSearchPage {

protected  WebDriver driver;


@FindBy(name="q")
private WebElement SearchBox;

@FindBy(name="btnG")
private WebElement SearchButton;    


public void SearchFor(String SearchTerm)
{
    SearchBox.sendKeys(SearchTerm);
    SearchButton.click();
}
```

}

### Class2

```
 public class TestSearchResults {
WebDriver driver;
GoogleSearchPage page;

@BeforeClass
public void Launch() throws Exception
{
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://google.com");
}

@AfterClass
public void Close()
{
    driver.quit();
}

@Test
public void ResultPage() {
    System.out.println(page);
    page=PageFactory.initElements(driver, GoogleSearchPage.class);
    page.SearchFor("selenium");

}
```

}

Could you please help how to verify the title after displaying the Search results

Note: I am using TestNG.

Thanks in Advance,
Shiva Oleti.

Answer (score 4):

**Try this:**

```
assertEquals("Your Page Title" , driver.getTitle());
```

`driver.getTitle()` - Returns `Title` of your current page.

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong but this answer does not tell us anything about how to approach this using the PageObject pattern which is a central part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can get & verify title of page using python webdriver. See below codes

```
driver.title('title name')
assert 'title name' in driver.title('title name')
```

It will verify the title name. if it is there title name test case pass else through assert error.

Answer (score 2):

Create a constructor in each page object.  The constructor:

- sets the instance driver value
- waits for page load to complete (e.g. loading spinner not visible, jQuery.active == 0, document.readyState == 'complete')
- verifies the page title (see other answers)
- Issue PageFactory.initElement(driver, this);

Therefore you don't need a separate method to verify title. In each step you will have a new YourPageObjectPage() which checks the title automatically. Think DRY.

Comment: Old question but I thought that visitors would like another option.